# Do authors usually receive a copy of the whole journal issue when they publish a paper?

Tags: publications, journals

I've recently published my first paper. 
Do journals usually send authors a copy of the issue in which their paper was published? Does Science magazine do that?

Comment: As for what's usual nowadays, in math at least: at most a free eprint, though occasionally an actual offprint--very rarely a copy of the whole issue.  Though Science is far from a typical research journal.

Comment: There are thousands of different journals, with many different policies. This question is too broad to answer. In the case of your particular paper, the journal should have made you aware of its policies before agreeing to accept the paper.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Should have" --- maybe.  "Did" --- often not.

Comment: Science do not offer a copy of the issue.

Comment: I am in your exact same situation: first paper, and in Science. Did you finally receive a copy of the issue? I want to frame it!

Comment: Did you just say you published you first journal paper? and it was in Science? Congratulations!

Answer (score 9):

Some journals do, and some journals don't.  In my experience, it seems pretty random which do and don't. Off the top of my head, I am not certain whether Science does.

Answer (score 4):

I got a dozen or so separate copies (in the format of the journal) of my papers when I published in some IEEE transaction a while back. Just the paper, not the whole issue. From other journals I got a copy of the issue, sometimes just a letter of confirmation that it was published, or not even that.

Answer (score 1):

There are far too many journals to make a single, authoritative statement on the issue, beyond "Not always".

In my experience, and in my field (biomedical) it's quite rate. Of the papers I've published, only the single paper I've gotten in *Lancet Infectious Diseases* provided full copies of the print journal. All other papers I have where I have a physical copy I either ordered, or happened to subscribe to the print journal already.

Answer (score 1):

No, Science does not give paper copies to authors, I was in your same situation. You can buy a separate issue if you request it, and it’s cheaper when yours is the current issue.